# PHP effect of error configurations on error_log function

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a set of PHP Unit Tests in my Laravel project and trying to not display errors when I run the tests in Terminal. I am logging the errors manually using error_log() function on every exception. I have tried to set php.ini error parameters to not display the errors but it seems like not working.

```
ini_set('log_errors', 0);
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);

error_log("This is an exception");
```

Even after the above setup, I am getting the string `This is an exception` in the console. Am I doing something wrong here? PHP version is 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there can be more then one `php.ini` file.  ie for the CLI `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and one for APACHE `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.  are you editing the correct file?

Comment: I am changing the ini settings during run time using PHP functions @cmorrissey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error_log` ini directive controls where the output from the `error_log()` function goes. When the directive is not set, the CLI will output to `stderr`. Additionally, if you can't set the directive for some reason, you could pass extra parameters to the `error_log()` function to control the output destination.

So, for example, if you wanted your errors to write out to `/var/log/php.log`, you have two options:

**ini directive:**

```
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/php.log');

error_log('destination set by error_log directive');
```

**error_log parameters:**

```
error_log(
    'destination set by parameters'.PHP_EOL, // this method doesn't auto append EOL; must add it manually
    3, // destination type; 3 = file
    '/var/log/php.log' // destination file
);
```

You can read more in the documenation:
[`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function
[`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) ini directive

Comment: Thanks @patricus! The `error_log` directive was not set and thus logs were outputting to `stderr`. I have set proper log file path and it worked!